# Trivial intersection of two normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose that $M$ and $N$ are two normal subgroups of a group $G$ such that $M\cap N = \{1_G\}$. Let $A, B$ are subgroups of $M$. If $AN=BN$ then $A=B$.

I start by showing $A\subseteq B$. Let $a\in A$ then $a\in AN = BN$ so $a = bn$ for some $b\in B$ and $n\in N$. I'm not sure how to show $a\in B$

Comment: $b^{-1}a \in M \cap N$.

Comment: So then $b^{-1}a = 1_G$ and thus $a = b\in B$. Would this be sufficient to complete the proof because the other inclusion will follow by a symmetrical argument?

Comment: By the way, there is no need to assume that $M$ and $N$ are normal subgroups. They could be any subgroups with trivial intersection.

Comment: @RMaharaj Yes, it's enough, using the symmetry of the problem